# how can I calculate the inverse of matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse, svd, pseudoinverse

Matrix has 16 rows and 1166 columns so I did not inverse directly. I have to calculate the SVD of matrix. I used the Matlab and I try to calculate pseudo inverse of matrix. 
[S V D]= svd(A)
A= S*V*D' and the diagonal singular values matrix V can be founda simply by replacing the diagonal entries with their multiplicative inverses am I right ? Because I am confused, my result is not correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: $[A]^{-1}=\frac {\text {adj}[A]}{\text {det}A]}$

Comment: but A matrix is not square.  how can ı write adj[A]?